# How did my Documents folder just disappear (NVMe SSD, Windows 10) - and how can I recover it?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I came to my computer today and saw that my Documents folder is missing. That's all my personal documents, just gone, poof! (No, I don't have a good backup!) It was perfectly fine last night.

#### Some backstory:

- Windows registers your "Documents" (formerly "My Documents") directory on-disk so your applications can find it if you moved or renamed it (e.g. to a separate disk).
- Thesedays a lot of software uses your Documents folder as a dumping ground for files that should really go into your `AppData` directory (formerly "Application Data" and "Local Settings").
- Because of that, I changed my Windows-registered "Documents"folder to `C:\Users\me\Apps` and then created a new directory named `C:\Users\me\Documents` which is not registered anywhere, and contains my actual personal documents.

I've been using this arrangement for the past 6 years without any problems, and it's entirely possible that it's unrelated to this current episode.

#### The problem

About an hour ago I opened my Windows User Profile directory to open a spreadsheet I keep stored in my Documents folder and I noticed the entire folder was missing, no trace of it at all.

I rebooted, hoping it's a glitch in Windows or something but after rebooting the directory was still gone. I loaded up some data recovery software to take a look, fearing the worst because my disk is an NVMe U.2 SSD with TRIM enabled - so if the delete command was issued by higher-level software then there's a risk everything would already be zeroed on the disk.

Fortunately the data recovery software showed the files still exists, but they don't exist in any directory structure on disk (at least as far as I can tell). The timestamps are all today around `15:17` - there's nothing relevant in my Windows Event log around that time.

I understand that, as the files still exist, they're simply "delinked" from the filesystem.

BTW, as soon as my computer rebooted I immediately disabled TRIM to prevent any unintentional loss of data.

Questions:

1. Are there any specific techniques for recovering full path information from these delinked files?
2. How could this have happened? How does a directory get deleted on Windows with TRIM enabled without losing the files contained within?

Comment: Are you looking in the correct profile directory?  Have you looked in `Windows.old`, although I suspect, a feature upgrade would fail given your configuration isn't standard.    If file recovery is finding the files, you should restore them, to another drive.  DO NOT RESTORE FILES TO YOUR DRIVE.

Comment: @Ramhound It gets worse. Recuva can see the files, but it's claiming their clusters have been overwritten by other files - mostly files included in today's Windows 10 update. Did the upcoming Windows 10 delete my files? This is awful.

Comment: Did the feature update delete your files, no your files were already deleted, the feature update overwrote the files.  There is a huge difference.  Feature updates DO NOT delete files when they are installed.

Comment: @Ramhound I speculate some bug in the Windows 10 update code deleted my folder, causing the files to be unlinked, then extracted the setup files which overwrote my unlinked files.

Comment: I have updated dozens of computers to 1809 today.  There isn't a bug.  The files were already deleted.  Of course you made no mention of the feature update being installed in your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't installed the feature update yet, but Windows unpacked it by itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84027/discussion-between-ramhound-and-dai).

Comment: Might as well at least try to recover the files (to a different drive as Ramhound recommends, copying to the same drive might overwrite them more), maybe not all sectors were overwritten, and maybe even partial (corrupted) files might still be of use. You really should not be running Windows on the same drive you're trying to recover, because it might overwrite things (like it did), using the drive read-only is best (with a live OS/ISO [linux & testdisk/photorec] or with another system drive or in another computer), but now even shutting Windows down might try installing/overwriting more stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have hit this bug with the recent Windows 10 1809 update: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/10/microsoft-suspends-distribution-of-latest-windows-10-update-over-data-loss-bug/

> Earlier this week Microsoft started distributing the Windows 10 October 2018 Update, version 1809, to Windows users that manually checked for updates. The company has now halted that rollout after many reports that installing it is causing serious data loss: specifically, deleting the Documents, and perhaps Pictures, folders.

There is no solution to get your data back other than using file recovery tools like you’ve been trying.

Comment: Indeed, this is what happened to me. It looks like only my Documents folder was affected, my Pictures folder seems intact.